# Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I used the following code in C#...

```
int totalValue = 0;
int total = 0;
totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) * int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString());

// This line causes the error
totalValue += Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString().Equals("Yes", StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 80 : 0;
```

... I received this error :

> Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

What does that error indicate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your argument for the second parameter of 'Equals' has the wrong type, so the compiler is identifying the wrong overload.

To fix it, change this:

```
StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
```

to this:

```
StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
```

Comment: For those struggling to find the actual solution, the problem is the `StringComparer` enum. The `Equals` call is resolving to the generic `object.Equals` method instead of `string.Equals`. 

You should use `StringComparision` enum so it uses `string.Equals` method.

Answer (score 21):

You are using wrong parameter type. You can use `Equals` as an instance level method or a type level (static) method:

```
string.Equals(str1, str2, StringComparison comp);

str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison comp);
```

So, in both, you need `StringComparison`, not `StringComparer`. And your one:

```
totalValue += Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString().Equals("Yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 80 : 0;
```

Comment: +1 only answer that highlights the issue is due to using StringComparer instead of the proper StringComparison.

Comment: +1 The problem is that Visual Studio may display a misleading error. Instance reference can be all right but a **method parameter can have the wrong type** - like StringComparison in @Stuck's case or the first string parameter in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's quite late and also may not apply to user's case directly, just adding this answer to help out those who face same issue but due to different reason.

`Equal()` method of a string instance needs first argument as `string` type.

So if by any chance first argument is not of `string` type and is of another type let's say `int`, you get the same error which can be misleading sometimes as it won't say first argument should be of type string directly.

Answer (score 2):

The Equals method is a Static method and you cannot access it via instance

```
string isChauffeurUsed = Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString();
totalValue += string.Equals(isChauffeurUsed, "Yes", 
                     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
              ? 80 
              : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct working code:

```
int totalValue = 0;
int total = 0;
totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) * int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString());

// This line
totalValue += Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString().Equals("Yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 80 : 0;
```

**Issue:**

You are using static property of **`StringComparer`**  class.
Rather use enum **`StringComparison`**.

As `String.Equals(str1,str2,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`
or `str1.Equals(str2,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);`

both takes enum StringComparison as there method argument.

Now this raises some questions, why you were not able to identify this mistake in your ide.

This is because, since **StringComparer** is an **abstract class** and **CurrentCultureIgnoreCase** is a **static getter property**, which returns an *object* of type **StringComparer** class.

i.e,

```
public static StringComparer CurrentCultureIgnoreCase { get; }
```

Thus the compiler is treating your "`Equals`" method as the "`Equals`" method of `Object Class`

i.e,

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB);
```

For some other who are curious about the use of **StringComparer** class.

So here is an example:

```
static void Main()
    {
        // Use these two StringComparer instances for demonstration.
        StringComparer comparer1 = StringComparer.Ordinal;
        StringComparer comparer2 = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

        // First test the results of the Ordinal comparer.
        Console.WriteLine(comparer1.Equals("value-1", "value-1")); // True
        Console.WriteLine(comparer1.Equals("value-1", "VALUE-1")); // False
        Console.WriteLine(comparer1.Compare("a", "b"));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer1.Compare("a", "a"));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer1.Compare("b", "a"));

        // Test the results of the OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer.
        Console.WriteLine(comparer2.Equals("value-1", "value-1")); // True
        Console.WriteLine(comparer2.Equals("value-a", "value-b")); // False
        Console.WriteLine(comparer2.Equals("value-1", "VALUE-1")); // True
        Console.WriteLine(comparer2.Compare("a", "B"));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer2.Compare("a", "A"));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer2.Compare("b", "A"));
    }
```

for more details follow https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringcomparer

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
totalValue += string.Equals(Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString(), "Yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 80 : 0;
```

(I couldn't compile that to test it, but I think it should work)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not strong.

`Session` is an object, it can be null, so if you want to use its value, please check the session first, and even the session's value is not a integer value.

I suggest you to do like this:

```
int? i = Session["s"] == null ? null : Parser.ParseInt(Session["s"].ToString());
```