# Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, comparison

*[Note: there's [another question about the same error-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773116/member-object-equalsobject-object-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-refer/11773224), but the root cause of the issue there is a bit different, and none of the answers there apply to the below code.]*

I have this code:

```
string localComputerName = Environment.MachineName;
foreach (StatsServer server in servers)
{
  if (localComputerName.Equals(server, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

which gives me this compile-error at the call to `Equals`:

> `Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

I was expecting it to use [string.Equals(string, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8), which is an instance method (not a static method); why does the compiler think I want object.Equals(object, object) instead?

Comment: String does not have method `Equals(object, StringComparison)`. It does not exists: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

Comment: @OlivierRogier, but it is overloaded onto all objects. My POCO doesn't declare a static `Equals` method either, but it's still in the autocomplete list. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: No, your method you want to call does not exists with the signature you wish, so your auto-answer solved your problem.

Comment: @OlivierRogier, yes it does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @OlivierRogier, no `StatsServer` isn't a string and that was the problem I addressed in my Answer. The two objects being compared have to be the same datatype or you'll get this error, and Visual Studio can point you in the wrong direction.

Comment: I made an answer. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200518/discussion-between-computercarguy-and-olivier-rogier).

Comment: This is actually *very* similar to the linked question. The problem there was that the OP was passing a argument of the wrong type for the *second* parameter, and the problem here was that you were passing an argument of the wrong type for the *first* parameter. I'm not convinced that that really warranted a separate question. But, OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that `string` is an `object`, but it's not the same type of `object` as `StatsServer`, so Visual Studio gets confused and thinks the `localComputerName` variable is the problem, instead of `server`.

From what I can determine, it decides this from the parameters of the `Equals` method, instead of by the datatype of from the variable the `Equals` is being applied to. (IMO, that's backwards, but evidently Microsoft has their reasons, and probably has something to do with how `Equals` is overloaded/extended onto all `object`s, or something.)

I this case, the error is a red herring. What needs to happen is that I should access the `ServerName` property/column of `server`, since it is a `string` and has the data I actually want for comparison:

```
if (localComputerName.Equals(server.ServerName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

The moral of the story is to make sure your `object`s are of the same datatype and to look at the whole line of code before assuming the JIT compiler is 100% accurate.

Comment: VS is right. You ask for a methode signature not found so the compiler found the static signature but it see that you don't use it as static, so the error. The error is relevant. What error do you want to have?